# Way to add brackets to dotwhisker in R without caption formatting changing?

Tags: r, ggplot2, brackets

I have a tidy dataframe with multiple models that I'm plotting as a dotwhisker plot. Below I've recreated a similar dataframe. This plot requires a caption explaining information about the predictors, and formats correctly when there are no brackets, but when brackets are added, it becomes duplicated at the bottom left. Is there any way around this, or reason why this happens? I would also be interested in putting the caption instead below the legends of the plot, but attempts using annotate and tag have also resulted in formatting problems. Thank you for any help! (Also, if this looks weird because 'model' and 'term' are already the same, the issue in the real code is with standardizing some names of the model to get colors correct, but shouldn't be an issue here).

```
results_df <- data.frame(
  model = c("Model 1","Model 1","Model 1","Model 1","Model 1", "Model 1",             
            "Model 2",  "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
            "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
            "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3",
            "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3",
            "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
            "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
            "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2"),
  estimate = c(-0.4890,  0.0966, -0.0911, -0.1700,  0.3620,  0.1980, -2.0920,
               -1.1620, -1.6910,-1.5320, -0.8340, -1.4350,  0.8240,  0.9750,
               0.9650, 0.5210,  0.9190,  0.9560, -0.9580, -0.1950, -1.1470, 
               -2.6430,-1.7420, -2.2500, -2.9990, -1.8100, -1.8270),
  conf.low = c(-0.6,  0.0, -0.2,-0.6,  0.0, -0.2, -2.4, -1.8, -1.9, -2.4,
               -1.8, -1.9,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,0.0, -3.0, -2.0,
               -1.9, -5.6, -3.6, -3.8, -3.0, -2.0, -1.9),
  conf.high = c(0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7,
                0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 1.1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.0,0.5, 0.7,
                0.0, 0.5, 0.7),
  term = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A",
           "B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","D","E",
           "F","G","H","I","J","K",
           "L"),
  fixed = c("Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects",
            "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",   
            "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects",
            "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",   
            "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects",
            "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",    "With Fixed Effects",   
            "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects",
            "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects",
            "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects", "Without Fixed Effects"),
  type = c("Model 1",              "Model 1",              "Model 1",             
           "Model 1",          "Model 1",              "Model 1",             
           "Model 2",  "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
           "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
           "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3",
           "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3",
           "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
           "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2",  
           "Model 2",   "Model 2",   "Model 2")
)
#recode model
results_df$model = results_df$type
#graph with all elements
full_graph = dwplot(results_df,
                    vline = geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2), 
                    dot_args = list(aes(shape = fixed)),
                    whisker_args = list(aes(colour = type)))
#add aesthetics to graph
full_graph = full_graph +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.justification=c(.02, .993),
        legend.background = element_rect(color="gray90"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.52),
        plot.caption = element_text(size=8, hjust = 0)) + 
  xlab("Coefficient Estimate") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2) +
  ggtitle("Graph Title") +
  scale_color_manual(name="Model",values=c("#52D871","#17D0E5","#EF5B3D"),
                     na.translate = F)+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Shape",values=c(16,17,16,17,16,17), na.translate = F)+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Model",values = c("#52D871","#17D0E5","#EF5B3D"),
                    na.translate = F)+
  labs(caption = "Note:
- notes about predictors
- additional notes
- additional notes
- additional notes
")
#look at graph, no formatting issues
full_graph
```

[image: Graph after brackets]

```
#add brackets
brackets = list(c("Bracket 1", "A", "C"), 
                c("Bracket 2", "D", "F"),
                c("Bracket 3", "G", "I"),
                c("Bracket 4","J","L"))
full_plot = full_graph %>% add_brackets(brackets)
#look at graph -- caption formatting now weird
full_plot[1]
```